# AsyncTask on Class that extends from Application vs AsyncTask on Service

Tags: android, web-services, android-asynctask

i need to check a web service every hour indefinetly on a project, i have a lot of activies and fragments and i dont want to call this webservice on every UI element that need it, rather i want to use an strategy to access that info from one place. I have seen on this video https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NJsq0TU0qeg, that using a service must be the last resort for doing a background task, so i figured out that i could call a webservice from a class that extends from Application and then retrieve that data via a public method that exposes the data from ws. but i have my doubts about which implementation its the best: AsyncTask on Class that extends from Application or AsyncTask on Service?

Comment: How about "neither"?

Comment: ok what do you suggest then?

Comment: See mjstam's answer.

Answer (score 2):

AsyncTask is great for running short ( and I mean short ) tasks in the background that are used by a specific activity.

For syncing data of a more general nature I don't think there is anything wrong with using an IntentService and then registering it to run periodically
with AlarmManager.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/AlarmManager.html